# How do I deal with "Error in FUN(X[[i]],..." when trying to add text labels to points with geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am brand spankin' new when it comes to R. Any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

I am using the choroplethr package to create maps by ZIP code. I want to add an overlay showing cities using `geom_point`.

My code is

```
t <- test.map +
  geom_point(data=lookup, aes(x=lat, y=lon), size=2, color="black", inherit.aes=FALSE) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=name),hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

where `test.map` is the plot from choroplethr, and `lookup` is a dataframe containing latitudes (lat), longitudes (lon), and location names (name).

`geom_text` returns the error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'name' not found

and I am not sure why.

Can you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @markus I added `data=lookup` and now I am getting an error reading: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found

Comment: @NelsonGon, thanks for showing me that. I will work on editing my question to comply.

Comment: @markus, that did it. I really appreciate the help. If you stick it in an answer, I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with OP's code is that `geom_point` and `geom_text` inherit data and aesthetics from what was used to create `test.map`

If we want to use a different data set for additional layers we need to specify the `data` argument in each of them and also set `inherit.aes` to `FALSE`.

```
test.map +
  geom_point(data=lookup, aes(x=lat, y=lon), size=2, color="black", inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=lookup, aes(label=name), hjust=0, vjust=0, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS You're welcome, glad I could help. For next time please share a reproducible example as Nelson suggested.